# Converting my Giant Roam 3 into more of a road bike, while keeping its hybrid identity?

Tags: road-bike, tire, handlebars

I am not rich so the budget is as low as possible. I use my bike for pleasure mostly as I am still a teenager. Of course I want speed, so I was wondering how well it would work if I changed the tires to thinner then they already are. Please tell me what size would be good, I ride on the road often, but I also use the sidewalk enough that a standard 700c tire would have to much vibration. I was also thinking about switching the handlebars to road bike style. Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I get smaller tires without changing my rims?](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/1935/can-i-get-smaller-tires-without-changing-my-rims) and [Upgrading straight handlebars to drop handlebars](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/1136/upgrading-straight-handlebars-to-drop-handlebars)

Comment: "Standard" 700C tires come in widths out to 40mm or more.  The amount of "vibration" in an unsuspended bike is directly related to tire pressure more than tire width.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what tires you have on the bike now. I'm wondering if the vibration you mention is due to "knobby" mountain bike tires or if there is some other cause.